# Woocommerce new product to external database using API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, external

I'm new to WordPress coding. I'm trying to get the product information to store into external db when a product is added by the vendor. I've tried to use Woocommerce built-in webhooks under API and tried to trigger a new PHP file as delivery URL that has Database connection and

`$object = WC_Product::get_post_data();
print_r($object);`

to get the product POST data and wanted to insert the data to db. For now, I'm just printing the array object so that I can write the query to insert into external database. File is invoked correctly, but I'm unable to get the newly posted product post data. I'm sure that I'm missing something to initiate before calling WC_Product.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? You could edit your question to add the important parts of your code.

Comment: Thank your for your response, Mariano. I'm having very little code on the file since I'm using built-in webhooks. However, I've edited my question.

Comment: At a minimum, I'd think you need the product/post ID. Otherwise, how will you know what product to get data for?